# Is react easy to integrate with already-created html and css files

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working with some developers to create a website, and I want to know if React will work if I hire someone to create the html and css first, and then have another person integrate react with those templates

Is react integratable in this situation, or does react have to be used from the get go? I am a python programmer, so I have no clue how react works lol

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of React is being able to generate HTML based on JavaScript code, if the HTML code is already done I'd find it kind of pointless to use React.

I am just a 2nd year student but I'd recommend to use React from the get go.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It should technically be possible to integrate react with already existing html/css files, just like you can manually alter the html and css files in your react project’s public folder, but you dont really provide a good reason for doing so. It might be easier, and more sustainable for maintaining the project to simply move your existing Html into a react project. If you dont have an actual good reason to use react for this project (like for example having primarily react-experienced developers on the team or needing to use specific react libraries and functionalities), there is no real harm in developing a website with plain html, css, and js.